# Nested Values in Column of a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unnest

I have a csv file called 'credits' whit three columns "crew", "cast" and 'id'. The result of applying df_credits['crew'][10] is as follows:

```
"[{'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adfa3', 'department': 'Camera', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 2702, 'job': 'Director of Photography', 'name': 'John Seale', 
          'profile_path': '/w4wp04pRMqJI2vt3gFTdIWLDDzp.jpg'}, 
  {'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adf8b', 'department': 'Directing', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 3026, 'job': 'Director', 'name': 'Rob Reiner', 
          'profile_path': '/2zw9Iq9uo4vZiTQNQWdNFwbA1TA.jpg'}, 
  {'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adf97', 'department': 'Production', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 3026, 'job': 'Producer', 'name': 'Rob Reiner', 
          'profile_path': '/2zw9Iq9uo4vZiTQNQWdNFwbA1TA.jpg'}, 
  {'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adfa9', 'department': 'Editing', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 3032, 'job': 'Editor', 'name': 'Robert Leighton', 
          'profile_path': None}, 
  {'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adf9d', 'department': 'Sound', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 9251, 'job': 'Music', 'name': 'Marc Shaiman', 
          'profile_path': '/aesoPh8jPR5qDKjjt7o5uj9kS3W.jpg'}, 
  {'credit_id': '52fe44dac3a36847f80adf91', 'department': 'Writing', 'gender': 2, 
          'id': 13520, 'job': 'Screenplay', 'name': 'Aaron Sorkin', 
          'profile_path': '/oFff5AbvrhmPW2WsyXV5cL7KURN.jpg'}]"
```

I need to unnest this values with python, trying different ways but I haven´t been able to do so...

Comment: Hi Jorge, what is your *desired* output? Also please post what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Looks like you want `pd.json_normalize` or `pd.read_json`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) to transform the string representation of the list to a list:

```
df_credits['crew'] = df_credits['crew'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
```